# PostgresSQL JSON query

Tags: json, postgresql

I have json stored in a column (oid) with the following structure:

```
{
  "fullName": "test test",
  "personDetails": {
    "address": "Advisor",
    "phoneNumber": "clare.railton@heptonstalls.co.uk"
  },
  "id": "6765788-yt67",
  "submittedDocument": {
    "answers": [
      {
        "questionId": "2",
        "responses": [
          {
            "value": "123456"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionId": "2.1",
        "responses": [
          {
            "IdA": 1,
            "IdB": 1,
            "value": "false"
          },
          {
            "IdA": 1,
            "IdB": 2,
            "value": "false"
          },
          {
            "IdA": 1,
            "IdB": 3,
            "value": "false"
          },
          {
            "IdA": 1,
            "IdB": 4,
            "value": "true"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
},
    "date": "2018-11-22",
    "PeriodId": 123456
}
```

How would i get the value of the response to all question numbers?  I have managed to get the json structure from the oid column using the lo_get function but i am struggling to capture the values i need.

Many thanks

Comment: What you mean *get the value of the response to all question numbers*?

Comment: So in the example given I would be looking to get 123456 back for questionId2.  For questionId 2.1 i would get 4 results (false, false, false, true).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a large object to store the json data?
Postgres can handle json columntypes in tables:

```
CREATE TABLE test_json (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, json json);
INSERT INTO test_json VALUES(1,'{
  "fullName": "test test",
  "personDetails": {
    "address": "Advisor",
    "phoneNumber": "clare.railton@heptonstalls.co.uk"
  },
  "id": "6765788-yt67",
  "submittedDocument": {
    "answers": [
      {
        "questionId": "2",
        "responses": [
          {
            "value": "123456"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionId": "2.1",
        "responses": [
          {
            "IdA": 1,
            "IdB": 1,
            "value": "false"
          },
          {
            "IdA": 1,
            "IdB": 2,
            "value": "false"
          },
          {
            "IdA": 1,
            "IdB": 3,
            "value": "false"
          },
          {
            "IdA": 1,
            "IdB": 4,
            "value": "true"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
},
    "date": "2018-11-22",
    "PeriodId": 123456
}');

SELECT json_extract_path(
json_array_elements(
json_extract_path(
json_array_elements(
json_extract_path((json),'submittedDocument','answers')
),'responses')
),'value'
)FROM test_json;
```

See:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: Unfortunately i have no option with the large object as the json storage as this was set-up by another person.  

I have managed to get the above to work.  Just another question - in reality there are more questionId's (sometimes hundreds) - what would be the best way to filter these so i only returned 1 questionId?